# After running boot-repair and disabeling secure-boot, still not booting to Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I recently got a Windows 10 laptop and wanted to set up a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 20.04.1. It was not my first setup of a dual-boot system, but the first which caused issues. I disabled secure boot and the Ubuntu-installation was successful, but even after restarting the device multiple times it was always directly booted into Windows directly. I set the UEFI boot order (I disabled BIOS) such that the Windows boot manager has lowest priority.

I also used the boot-repair by booting a live session from the installation USB. The repair claimed to be successful with this output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z5xcdhgjcC
However, I could observe no effect. I executed the recommended command in the Windows command prompt.
Note that in the UEFI boot order menu, I cannot find GRUB or UBUNTU. Instead, I am shown NVMe1 and NVMe0 INTEL SSDPEKKF512G8L.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? What model Lenovo? UEFI update required for USB-C port issues 2017 thru 2019 models
ThinkPad models including the ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen to 7th Gen), X1 Yoga (2nd Gen to 4th Gen), and P-series 
https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/  The reinstall of grub added an Ubuntu entry. Is it now shown in UEFI boot menu? It is shown as 0001 with Windows as 0000. But UEFI boot order was set to devices, your NVMe drives. And shimx64.efi  was copied to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi on nvme0n1.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have a 2019 ThinkPad X1 Extreme.  I did run the Lenovo Software Updater which updated the UEFI. I read that there was a version which had Linux issues but it is not the one which I have installed. 
In the UEFI boot menu, no Ubuntu option is shown, but only the Windows boot manager and the drives.

Comment: Because the one drive entry was modified to use Ubuntu's shimx64.efi as bootx64.efi, does that drive now boot Ubuntu? Drive or fallback entry is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. With Windows that is a copy of Windows .efi boot file. Boot-Repair typically backs that up and copies shimx64.efi to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Currently none of the drives boots Ubuntu. I do not manage to get any Ubuntu booted without the live session. When starting the boot manual boot selection (F12 during the Lenovo startup), NVMe0 I is shown but selecting it does eventually boot Windows again.

Comment: Have you tried the BCD edit per line 120 in report. Sometimes that is also required.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it had no effect.

Comment: I do not recommend the change of Windows boot entry to actually be Ubuntu's shim file, anymore. Most UEFI only check name, not actual boot file. But if booting drives, lets you boot Windows it may work. You really need a direct way to boot Windows from UEFI as grub only boots working Windows, so it does not always work. Also make Windows repair/recovery flash drive as well as Ubuntu live installer. See IV. for efibootmgr entry to have Windows description & shim boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Okay I did a live session and tried 'sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"' . I got the notification that there are two entries called "Windows Boot Manager", 0001 and 0000. Boot order is, other than in the setting that I did in the UEFI Menu, 0000 and then 001A (NVMe0).

After restart, it started into Windows again. :(

 Also, a vaguely related stupid newbie question: For the live session I use the installation drive in the "Try Ubuntu"-mode. This says it wouldn't change the computer. But I just used it for exactly this purpose, didn't I?

Comment: Using live installer will not automatically change anything, but you can typically do just about anything. Did you try manually selecting both Windows entries?

Comment: I did another live session and noticed that the changes I did before were reset; there was again only one Windows Boot Manager. The Boot order showed  NVMe0, then all the other stuff. I did execute the renaming again and put the new Boot entry to the front, however, it did boot again in Windows. I also set the timeout up to 15, because it was set to 0 before.

Comment: Does your UEFI have some sort of security setting that prevents changes or resets them? Some like HP, do not accept efibootmgr boot order changes (boots once). You have to change boot order in UEFI settings. Others like Acer require Secure boot on & password to allow additional required setting changes. But if UEFI password lost you convert system to a brick. Most reset password or have one they will not lose.

Comment: Yes that was it, I overlooked that option! Thank you so much! You saved my day!