# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Thinkpad X1 carbon: Corrupted the solid state storage. Boot from USB Ubuntu 20.04 installation stick to fix?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, storage

I recently purchased a Thinkpad Carbon X1 computer that does not have a CD drive.  I tried to install Ubuntu, using Unetbootin; when I booted Unetbootin, it appeared to be installing Ubuntu 20.04 -- but the process went on for over a day, stuck at one point.  Instead of terminating the attempted installation, I foolishly rebooted.

The result is, that the solid state storage was thoroughly corrupted.

Tomorrow, I'll purchase a USB flash drive, and turn it into an Ubuntu 20.04 installation device.  (I have a Dell Latitude computer that runs Ubuntu 20.04 perfectly; I've downloaded the .iso file to be burned into a new Flash drive, and the necessary burner software.)

I plan to place the thus created Ubuntu flash drive into the Thinkpad and boot the Thnkpad.

I'm hoping that Ubuntu 20.04 will pop up, and that I'll be able to install Ubuntu 20.04 on the solid state storage device, turning the Thinkpad into a usable Ubuntu computer, from which I can remove the USB device.

Am I missing a few things?

Thanks,

--  Saul

Comment: If you have an Ubuntu computer, I would use mkusb to create your Persistent Live USB. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: Buy a few flash drives, so you have backups & can keep Ubuntu live installer on one smaller one or larger with persistence or space for storage. Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2019 UEFI settings required.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291280/after-running-boot-repair-and-disabeling-secure-boot-still-not-booting-to-grub
Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th Gen LITEON CA3 SSD issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447687

Answer (score 0):

I created a bootable Ubuntu installation flash drive on my Dell Legacy Ubbuntu computer by Burning a downloaded .iso file onto the flash drive using the standard ap "Startup Disk Creator".  I plugged the USB device into the Thinkpad, and truned on the Thinkpad.  The hard drive of the Thinkpad had been so corrupted that I had to do a little fiddling to get the Thinkpad to boot from the USB stick; but I succeeded, and th installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on the Thinkpad proceeded with absolutely no problems. In fact, I'm posting this note using the Thinkpad.
:)
One (minor) remaining problem:  The Thinkpad's Trackpad doesn't work (that's what made the computer cheap :).  My workaround:  I use an optical mouse.
(I wonder if it is possible and easy to replace the Trackpad with a working one?)

--  Saul