Why is Ubuntu not accessible after successful installation?
I have now installed Ubuntu three times. However, I dont know how to start Ubuntu and cannot find any trace of Ubuntu on my laptop.
Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Anything else I could try?
Here is the list of (I guess) relevant details:

X1 Carbon 10th Gen (Type 21CB), with Windows 11 (current, reinstalled last week with all updates)

ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64 (latest version)

ISO image written to new USB stick with RUFUS (latest version).


Ubuntu installation (as a second OS, alongside existing Windows) successfully completed (only WiFi connection cannot be established).


When I restart, I can't select Ubuntu instead of Windows anywhere. It only ever starts Windows.

Only Windows is available in System Configuration > Boot:


Also in the boot menu only Windows is available:


Secure Boot is off:


Detail: My Windows obviously doesn't have the quick start function. Startup always takes about 30 seconds.


EDIT

Meanwhile I bought a second SSD to install Ubuntu as the only OS, hoping to make things simpler.

Again, the installation from USB-Stick seems successful (this time WLAN connects immediately).

However on restart the laptop goes in an endless loop of restarting, Ubuntu doesn't start.

Restarting with USB-Stick plugged starts the installation process again. However if I cancel the installation menu window I after the media validation black screen I am suddenly in the Ubuntu desktop. Nothing here persists to the next restart of this type.


sudo fdisk -l
 

sudo lsblk -o


lsblk -ape7


Bootinfo summary report https://pastebin.com/wnBXmcqU

When I continue with the installation I am forced to manual partitioning and I see these partitions (I did not partition deliberately anything before). Here the continue button remains inactive, I cannot continue, no matter what I choose, including after overwriting new empty partition


and later


I read on ubuntu.com that Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen10 is not officially on the list of verified devices for tha lates two releases.

Boot-repair summary report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MG6kwFrrn7/


Installing linux should be easy and straight forward, isn't it?
How is all that possible?
I'm in disbelief.

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
May be best to see if installed & details:

Find the way to get the "Boot menu" as you start the PC, Ubuntu disk/partition in there? Boot it. If not possible boot the installation media and open a terminal; do lsblk -ape7 and add the output text to your posting.

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

From a live Ubuntu session, run: sudo fdisk -l and sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL, copy and paste the outputs, editing your post.

In the Boot Menu screenshot, you have "Windows Boot Manager" and "NVMe0: WD blah blah". What happens if you put the NVMe0 one first? That is probably where your Linux bootloader has been installed.

@terdon This starts Windows

@kyodake see edits in the post.

@Hannu see edits in the post.

@oldfred see edit in the post.

Directly post terminal output in initial question, not screenshots. And loops do not need to be included, they are just your snap apps. Did you open the Boot-Repair link to run the commands. After adding ppa & updating as shown, then: sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair  And just post link to the Summary Report in pastebin  in question.

@oldfred ok, I run boot-repir and added the paste-bin link in the post. Problem seems to be there is no boot-loader.

You do not want boot files in MBR as that is for old BIOS systems. Boot files should be in ESP, your nvme0n1p1. But report is not showing that. Is Windows fast startup or bitlocker on. That may lock partitions. Some Lenovo's also have added settings in UEFI settings to prevent USB boot or install of other boot loaders. Check Windows & UEFI settings. Lenovo T450 Problem with boot repair GRUB - Boot Lock issue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494747
Lenovo Locked UEFI/BIOS setting:
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Foygxuo193ui41.jpg

@oldfred no windows fast start up. Actually no windows at all, its a brand new empty SSD. Checked UEFI settings, dont see what else I could change. downloaded super grub2 disk but dont know how to start it.

Why is there no bootloader on my system? How can I install a bootloader that is recognized by ubuntu?

I have a mainstream laptop and I cannot install a mainstream OS, why? What would you do in my situation?

Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? And SSD firmware also. Some Lenovo have an UEFI setting like this: Lenovo T450 Problem with boot repair GRUB - Boot Lock issue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494747  Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2019 UEFI settings required.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291280/after-running-boot-repair-and-disabeling-secure-boot-still-not-booting-to-grub
